# How to retrieve data from SQL database for a logged in user

Tags: php, mysql, session

I want to have a profile page so the logged in user can view their personal information.
Im able to display the current logged in username but unable to display any other information. 
The remaining data is stored within the same table as the username.

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); 
define('DB_NAME', 'Pole_Fitness'); 
define('DB_USER','root'); 
define('DB_PASSWORD','root'); 

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 

session_start(); 
$_SESSION['userName']
$userName = $_SESSION['userName']

    $getquery=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM WebsiteUsers WHERE userName = '$userName'");
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery))
    {
    $FirstName=$rows['FirstName'];
    $LastName=$rows['LastName'];
    $DOB=$rows['DOB'];

    echo $FirstName . '<br/>' . '<br/>' . $LastName . '<br/>' . '<br/>' . $DOB '<hr size="3"/>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What is your table structure? What have you tried doing to debug the issue? Have you tried to print_r $rows to see if it contains any data?

Comment: Table Structure:
userID - int (Auto Increment)
FirstName - varchar
LastName - varchar
userName - varchar
email - varchar
pass - archer
DOB - date


Im using Sublime text. Im new to PHP could you suggest a way to debug my code?
And no I haven't used print_r$rows

Answer (score 0):

you seem to be missing a **.**, as concatenate operator, just after you $DOB variable on the line where you get to print the data. Can you make sure that it goes like this:

```
 echo $FirstName . '<br/><br/>' . $LastName . '<br/><br/>' . $DOB . '<hr size="3"/>';
```

I joined both break tags to make it more concise. Also those session assignments you did seems to be out of place, let's clean it up a bit:

```
session_start(); 
//$_SESSION['userName'] - how bout commenting this out
$userName = $_SESSION['userName']; //missing ampersand
```

Take note that mysql_query is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, so you might want to use mysqli extensions instead.

Comment: Thank you Vincent! The code works perfectly! I have been struggling for a few days now so thanks :D